# Entity Framework - No Repository abstraction

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, I need to use EF and abstract the queries from the Presentation layer. Based from what I've been reading questions and answers all over the net, EF is built having repository pattern on it's DbSet and Unit of work on DbContext.

Repository pattern can easily do the requirement but I don't wanna repeat this implementation and now confused where should I initialize or access the DbContext. Should it be on the service layer?

MVC4 Api will be used for this project

Comment: If you don't want your own repository layer... where else?

Comment: well it's not that I wanted totally to scrape the repository, I just want not to create a new repository implementation similar to what other tutorial does. Is the IDbSet will play a big role on this game?

Comment: I think there is quite a bit of confusion around the repository issue with DbContext.  I'm working on a WPF - MVVM application, and I ended up not using repositories, but just using the built in dbSet's which works fairly well.  I am interested to hear others opinions on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I have seen this done in the past is to essentially remove the DbContext's dependency on a physical database by creating an interface for your context then make your data access calls from your Services Layer (Business Logic Layer).

There is however, a disadvantage in using this approach, which is the fact that your unit tests (which will be using a Fake implementation of your DbContext) will be using LINQ to Objects to run your queries whereas your concrete implementation will use LINQ to Entities which does not support all LINQ to Objects methods.

There's documentation on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) which highlights these differences.

I also recommend reading this article (http://kearon.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/mocking-entity-framework-4-code-first.html) which demonstrates how to make DbContext unit testable by removing the inderlying dependency on a phyiscal database.

Hope this all helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I get it right, I'll be accessing the DbContext from the service layer? Is it okay to do that? Well for the disadvantage part, I guess I have to do an integration test there

Comment: Yes it's absolutely fine; Doing it this way will effectively remove the dependency on the underlying data store. And integration testing will definitely make the incompatibilities come to the surface.

Comment: Thanks Mez. I think this is the answer that I'm looking for